# how to populate a render fragment in a component

Tags: blazor

Someone has written the following 'card' component (code reduced for brevity):

```
<div class="aks-card @RoundBaseCssClass @CssClass">
    <div class="@HeaderCssClass">
        @Header
    </div>
    <div class="aks-card-body">
        @Body
    </div>
    <div class="@RoundBaseCssClass @ActiveCssClass">
        @Actions
    </div>
</div>
```

each of the @Header, @Body and @Actions are declared in the form :

```
[Parameter]
 public RenderFragment Header { get; set; }
```

I'm now trying to use this component in another component so In a parent I have:

```
<card></card>
```

which renders the basic above. The issue i'm having is how do I set the values of the Parameters So for example I want Header to show `<h4>My card header</h4>` But I'm having trouble doing this. Can someone show me how I should set this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage would look like

```html
<Card>
    <Header>Hello</Header>
    <Body>World</Body>
    <Actions> some (Blazor) html </Actions>
</Card>
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
<Card>
  <Header>
    <h4>My card header</h4>
  </Header>
  <Body>
    .. body markup
  </Body>
  <Actions>
    ... actions markup
  </Actions>
</Card>
```

The content is markup not a `RenderFragment`, but the Razor pre-compiler builds the markup into a `RenderFragment` in the compiled class object that represents the component.

**FYI** The default setup looks like this.

```
<Card>
    <h4>My card header</h4>
</Card>
```

For a card component that looks like this

```
<div>
 @ChildContent
</div>

@code {
[Parameter] public RenderFragment ChildContent {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: You can't make a `<card>`.   Proper use of capitals is enforced.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - Give me a break ;-) I've just got a new computer this afternoon with a Logic MX Keys keyboard, and my figners are haivng troulbe funding the wronmg keys!

Comment: @bilpor,  I'm of the opinion that this should be the accepted answer. Accepted answers are a way to indicate to askers where to look for help. I always consult only accepted answers.